# How do I compare elements in a variable using Bash?

Tags: bash

I have 2 variables that both hold 6 values each, and I'm struggling to figure out how to compare the values. I'm not even sure how to check their type to be quite honest, after searching.

Here's one of the functions:

```
localfiles="$(ls -l string_matching_pattern_* | awk '{print $5}')"
#Matches to the string_matching_pattern and then assigns their file sizes to the variable localfiles

echo "$localfiles"
```

```
10
123
4873
8734
2109
```

The second function is essentially the same thing, but grabs the file sizes from an AWS S3 bucket:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder1 | awk '{print $3}'
s3files="$(aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder1 | awk '{print $3}')"
echo "$s3files"
```

```
10
123
4873
8734
1111
```

So basically, how do I compare those outputs or the values of whatever is in `localfiles` to `s3files`

Comment: @chepner: OP is parsing `ls` to get file size...

Comment: `localsizes=(stat -c '%s' string_matching_pattern_*)`, then. (Or whatever form your local `stat` requires, but still [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: Put them in an array rather than a string, then loop over the array indexes.

Comment: @chepner should be `localsizes=$(stat -c '%s' string_matching_pattern_*)`. Had me confused for a second there

Comment: `localsizes=( $(stat -c '%s' string_matching_pattern_*) )`, for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given:

```
$ localfiles="10                      
123
4873
8734
2109"
$ s3files="10
123
4873
8734
1111"
```

you could do

```
$ paste -d"-" <(echo "$localfiles") <(echo "$s3files") | bc
0
0
0
0
998
```

or

```
$ while read -u3 localsize; read -u4 s3size; do
    echo $((localsize - s3size))
done 3<<<"$localfiles" 4<<<"$s3files"
0
0
0
0
998
```

With arrays:

```
$ unset localfiles s3files
$ localfiles=( 10 123 4873 8734 2109 )
$ s3files=( 10 123 4873 8734 1111 )
$ for i in "${!localfiles[@]}"; do echo $(( ${localfiles[i]} - ${s3files[i]} )); done
0
0
0
0
998
```

Comment: In the 2nd alternative that starts with `while read`, are `localsize` and `s3size` filenames? Or are they variables? I'm just a bit lost on that and the 3rd line with `done 3<<<"$localfiles" 4<<<"$s3files"`

Comment: `<<<` is a ["here-string"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings). Like other redirections, you can provide a file descriptor, here I'm using `3` and `4` so the `read` commands can pick up each line from the proper string due to the respective `-u` options. In the last iteration, the variable `localsize` has the value `2109` and the variable `s3size` has the value `1111`

Comment: What's the proper way to call the indices in an `if` statement inside the `while` loop? I've tried `if [ ((localsize - s3size)) -eq 0 ];` and it isn't working

Comment: Glenn, what is the purpose of `3` and `4` in the last line of `done 3<<<"$localfiles" 4<<<"$s3files"`? I'm a little stumped on figuring out what that does

Answer (score 0):

Save the values to arrays instead of variables, this should make your values easier to compare:

```
local_sizes=()
s3_sizes=()

for i in $(ls -l string_matching_pattern_* |awk '{print $5}')
do    
    local_sizes+=($i)
done

for i in $(aws s3 ls s3://bucket/folder1 | awk '{print $3}')
do
    s3_sizes+=($i)
done

printf '%s\n' "${local_sizes[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${s3_sizes[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks - was trying to figure it out. Per @chepner 's suggestion, I replaced the `ls` command and function with `stat`

Comment: Code sample here follows lots of bad practices. See http://shellcheck.net/ output when given same, as well as http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs; likewise, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087

Comment: BTW, `printf '%s\n' "${arrayname[@]}"` is a much cheaper/easier/faster way to print all contents of an array, newline-delimited.

Comment: quoted some of my variables as per shellcheck's recommendations. I know there are better solutions than using ls, was trying to follow what OP was doing in his post